# Нужно вычленить дату из строки и проверить ее на подлинность методами 7 и 8 версий Java

Tags: java, дата

"Обработать  данные, выделив нужные для задачи части (например, в строке встречается день недели, год и месяц,  дата в разных комбинациях в строке «Я любил 1999 год, а особенно февраль, который состоял из 29 дней»).

Из этого примера вычленяется год - 1999, месяц - февраль, кол-во дней - 29.

Нужно вычислить количество дней в месяце в указанном году и проверить правильность из строки (Java 7-).

Вычислить количество дней в месяце в указанном году и проверить правильность из строки (Java 8+)."

Думаю, с помощью Regex можно дату вычленить. А как сравнивать даты не понимаю

Comment: Если год и количество дней именно в таком порядке идут, то просто с помощью регулярки `\d+` оба числа вытаскивайте, переводите в числа, сравниваете как числа. Не знаю что за выражение и где вы ищите.

Comment: Написано, что в строке в разных комбинациях дата встречается. Но это не столь важно, более вопрос с датами интересен

Comment: Тогда просто уберите знаки препинания, разбейте на отдельные слова по пробелам, проверьте каждое слово на вхождение в списки месяцев, дней недели и т.д.

Comment: попалась такая же задача, скажите смогли вы ее решить и если да то как?